# I would like to know what software was used to edit this photo?

Tags: photo-editing

[image]
Does anyone know what specific software was used to create this style of picture? I am an amateur photographer, and I primarily take sports pictures of my sons. I have used old versions of photoshop, and also use paint, but I have not been able to match this style of picture. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this meta question](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) and please rephare the title and/or content?

Comment: Are you certain that is a photo? E.g. these http://jasondegraaf.blogspot.ch/ are "real" paintings.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say it at 100% but the basis should be done by using [HDR plus Topazlab Adjust](http://www.topazlabs.com/adjust) plugin.
The final result is not only due to this filter of course.

[image: an example]

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a painting effect of some type and is just a filter.  It appears related to an emboss filter, but preserving color.  There is no way to tell the exact software used.  Try looking at the Stylize filters in Photoshop.

Comment: Note that personally, I would try to avoid filters like this like the plague.  It removes details and makes the photo look really bad.  It might work for trying to save an otherwise unusable photo, but I wouldn't make it a goal as an end result.